# Linux Bash Alert Script /var/log/message

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command, alert

I am trying to make an alert script that will run every 5min on my linux machine I only want the latest data to have an output and the data that already emailed will not be show anymore

```
tail -n1 /var/log/message | grep suppress | mail-s 'suppress' test@hotmail.com
```

On my command above it will run the same data over and over again until I received a new suppress alert

Comment: Try using xargs and tail's `-f`: `tail -f -n1 /var/log/messages | grep --line-buffered suppress | xargs -rd'\n' -n1 sh -c 'printf "%s\n" "$@" | mail-s suppress testt@hotmail.com; sleep 5m' --`

Comment: Save timestamp and line number of last line.

Comment: `printf "%s\n" "$@" | mail-s suppress test@hotmail.com` can be simplified to `mail-s suppress test@hotmail.com <<< "$1"` since there's only one line/argument being processed.

Comment: when i tried to run this command it directs me to the   > in command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your scrip runs exactly every 5 minutes (perhaps using crontab), you can use

```
find /var/log/message -mmin -5 -exec grep suppress {} \; |
  tail -1 | 
  mail-s 'suppress' test@hotmail.com
```

EDIT: How to skip processing when the pipe is empty? Don't use the pipeline:

```
msg=$(find /var/log/message -mmin -5 -exec grep suppress {} \; | tail -1)
test -n "$msg" && 
   echo "$msg" | 
   mail-s 'suppress' test@hotmail.com
```

EDIT 2:
Please note, that you will get an old `suppress` line, when the log gets new lines without `suppress` in it. You will need more scripting to solve this (remember linenumber where the match was found or nr of matches ad compare) and also find a solution when the /var/log/message file is rotated.
Perhaps you should do something like

```
msg=$(diff /var/log/message /tmp/oldmessages | grep suppress | tail -1)
test -n "$msg" && 
  cp /var/log/message /tmp/oldmessages &&
  echo "$msg" | 
  mail-s 'suppress' test@hotmail.com
```

Comment: This is okay but my only problem now it will still email with an empty content every 5min

Comment: Sorry, it was a buggy solution. I made an improvement.